# Lejos giving error on initializing matrix

Tags: java, matrix, lejos-nxj

We are trying to build a robot and for the robot to understand where he is right now we are going to use a matrix.

So i'm calling out the matrix. java without anything from the main.
And then trying to use the initMatrix, it just gives me an error.

```
public class Matrix {

    // Matrix creation
    public String[][] maturix = new String[10][10];
    // Recorded Position of the Robot
    public int x=0;
    public int y=10;
    public int Ox;
    public int Oy;
    public String Orientation = "East"; //Initializing the robot East-oriented to help place Obstacles (either Walls or Sheep) and walking

    public void initMatrix()
    {
        // Summary: E = Empty; G = Sheep; W = Wall; C =  current position; F = Finishing Line; X = Null; U = Unknown


        maturix[10][0] = "S"; //Starting Position
        maturix[10][1] = "U";
        maturix[10][2] = "U";
        maturix[10][3] = "U";
        maturix[10][4] = "U";
        maturix[10][5] = "U";
        maturix[10][6] = "U";
        maturix[10][7] = "U";
        maturix[10][8]= "U";
        maturix[10][9] = "U";
        maturix[10][10] = "U";
        maturix[9][1] = "X";
        maturix[9][2] = "U";
        maturix[9][3] = "X";
        maturix[9][4] = "U";
        maturix[9][5] = "X";
        maturix[9][6] = "U";
        maturix[9][7] = "X";
        maturix[9][8] = "U";
        maturix[9][9] = "X";
        maturix[9][10] = "U";
        maturix[8][0] = "U";
        maturix[8][1] = "U";
        maturix[8][2] = "U";
        maturix[8][3] = "U";
        maturix[8][4] = "U";
        maturix[8][5] = "U";
        maturix[8][6] = "U";
        maturix[8][7] = "U";
        maturix[8][8] = "U";
        maturix[8][9] = "U";
        maturix[8][10] = "U";
        maturix[7][0] = "U";
        maturix[7][1] = "X";
        maturix[7][2] = "U";
        maturix[7][3] = "X";
        maturix[7][4] = "U";
        maturix[7][5] = "X";
        maturix[7][6] = "U";
        maturix[7][7] = "X";
        maturix[7][8] = "U";
        maturix[7][9] = "X";
        maturix[7][10] = "U";
        maturix[6][0] = "U";
        maturix[6][1] = "U";
        maturix[6][2] = "U";
        maturix[6][3] = "U";
        maturix[6][4] = "U";
        maturix[6][5] = "U";
        maturix[6][6] = "U";
        maturix[6][7] = "U";
        maturix[6][8] = "U";
        maturix[6][9] = "U";
        maturix[6][10] = "U";
        maturix[5][0] = "U";
        maturix[5][1] = "X";
        maturix[5][2] = "U";
        maturix[5][3] = "X";
        maturix[5][4] = "U";
        maturix[5][5] = "X";
        maturix[5][6] = "U";
        maturix[5][7] = "X";
        maturix[5][8] = "U";
        maturix[5][9] = "X";
        maturix[5][10] = "U";
        maturix[4][0] = "U";
        maturix[4][1] = "U";
        maturix[4][2] = "U";
        maturix[4][3] = "U";
        maturix[4][4] = "U";
        maturix[4][5] = "U";
        maturix[4][6] = "U";
        maturix[4][7] = "U";
        maturix[4][8] = "U";
        maturix[4][9] = "U";
        maturix[4][10] = "U";
        maturix[3][0] = "U";
        maturix[3][1] = "X";
        maturix[3][2] = "U";
        maturix[3][3] = "X";
        maturix[3][4] = "U";
        maturix[3][5] = "X";
        maturix[3][6] = "U";
        maturix[3][7] = "X";
        maturix[3][8] = "U";
        maturix[3][9] = "X";
        maturix[3][10] = "U";
        maturix[2][0] = "U";
        maturix[2][1] = "U";
        maturix[2][2] = "U";
        maturix[2][4] = "U";
        maturix[2][5] = "U";
        maturix[2][6] = "U";
        maturix[2][7] = "U";
        maturix[2][8] = "U";
        maturix[2][9] = "U";
        maturix[2][10] = "U";
        maturix[1][0] = "U";
        maturix[1][1] = "X";
        maturix[1][2] = "U";
        maturix[1][3] = "X";
        maturix[1][4] = "U";
        maturix[1][5] = "X";
        maturix[1][6] = "U";
        maturix[1][7] = "X";
        maturix[1][8] = "U";
        maturix[1][9] = "X";
        maturix[1][10] = "U";
        maturix[0][0] = "U";
        maturix[0][1] = "U";
        maturix[0][2] = "U";
        maturix[0][3] = "U";
        maturix[0][4] = "U";
        maturix[0][5] = "U";
        maturix[0][6] = "U";
        maturix[0][7] = "U";
        maturix[0][8] = "U";
        maturix[0][9] = "U";
        maturix[0][10] = "5";

    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the error that you get?

Comment: Uncaught exception

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array indexes in java are 0-based.

So, if you type `maturix[10][0]` you are accessing the *11th* element. Add 1 to the  declaration, `public String[][] maturix = new String[11][11];`

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix is defined as:

```
public String[][] maturix = new String[10][10];
```

but that means that you can acces only indeces in a range [0,9] (10 elements).

You have to define:

```
public String[][] maturix = new String[11][11];
```